# Validate EditText input whenever user press BACK/HOME/RECENTS

Tags: android

I cannot find a complete answer for this question so I'll put it again here. I have an EditText, which requires validation every time the user finishes editing. A lot of answers online rely on method `editText.setOnEditorActionListener()` to detect user pressing `Done`. However, this methods doesn't detect if the user presses the three hard keys (Back, Home, and the third one). I want to trust the user to always press `Done` but that's highly unlikely. Please help me out on this issue; and also the name of the third button.

Edit: if there is no validation in place, is there a way to revert all changes made? For example, whenever the user presses BACK, HOME or RECENTS, all changes will be gone?

Comment: Why are you attempting to validate an `EditText` that the user is destroying (BACK) or moving into the background (HOME, RECENTS)?

Comment: Well for example, by default my EditText has value `50`. And it needs to has a value at all times (when I navigate to parent view, value EditText will be fetched back). The user can cheat by delete value in EditText, and then press BACK button. `setOnEditorActionListener()` won't trigger and EditText field remains empty. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well if this question is too tricky then is there a way to make them actually "destroy" their edits? E.g. whenever they hit BACK or HOME or RECENTS, all changes will be reverted back to original

Comment: onPause() is where you deal with the user leaving your activity, you can use this method to validate your textview in case user press home or back key.

Comment: "Does that make sense?" -- not really.

Answer (score 0):

Try validating it in `onDestroy` and `onPause`.

When user press HOME (BACK), `onPause` (`onDestroy`) will be invoked. So you do something like this there

```
String text = myEditText.getText().toString();
if (text.equals("")) {
// The EditText is empty. Do nothing.
} else {
// Make the changes here.
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this answers the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

Try some Like This:

```
String finalText;


 tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.charCounts);
    textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
    textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               finalText=  tv.getText().toString();
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    }); 


public boolean methodOfValidation(String finalText){

if ( finalText.equals("myCorrectText") )
return true;
else
 return false;

}

   @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

if(!methodOfValidation(finalText))
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR ERROR", toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
    finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way u follow ur task.u ll easily validate ur all editText. Inside Button u have to use this.

> `String grpn=edittext1.getText().toString();
>
>        String star=edittext2.getText().toString();
>
>        String en=edittext13.getText().toString();`
>   
>   `if( grph.equalsIgnoreCase("Select"))
>       {`e`

```
else if(star.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set the date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}                   
else if(en.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
 {
```

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please set group no", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }`